# Nginx reverse proxy errors on JS

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

We have certain sites we need to mask our client IP addresses with a proxy when they browse to those sites. I have built NGINX on AWS Linux 2023. It works with simply google.com but does not work with any site using .js. Not sure what to try next.I have a domain --> A record --> ALB w/Cert --> EC2 w/Nginx

```
server {
   listen       443;
   server_name  ==my LB A-record==.com;

   proxy_connect_timeout       120;
   proxy_send_timeout          120;
   proxy_read_timeout          120;
   send_timeout                120;

   proxy_buffer_size   8k;
   proxy_buffers       16 8k;

   proxy_http_version 1.1;

   proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $server_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $server_addr;

   location / {
      proxy_bind $server_addr;
      proxy_pass https://myapplications.microsoft.com/;
   }
   access_log  /var/log/nginx/nbis/access.log;
   error_log   /var/log/nginx/nbis/error.log;
}
```

Error:
Refused to execute script from 'https://==my LB A-record==/bundle/low-change-freq-vendors.54a65ab6.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

It SOMETIMES works. Why is the URL not changing to myapps? Why the MIME error?